# Stop Sencha TOuch suspendEvents from queuing events

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I read about Sencha Touch's **suspendEvents** and **resumeEvents** commands.

I have used them, they seem to work fine.

The problem is that **suspendEvents** makes the events bubble, and they resume after the **resumeEvents** command is triggered.

Is there a way to prevent that?

I saw this aproach, but it does not work: `suspendEvents(false)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually resumeEvents has option "discardQueuedEvents". So I guess you should try with resumeEvents()